# Using SqlQuery to get IQueryable

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is there something that can return `IQueryable`for a dynamic sql query in Entity Framework 6?

This is what I am using now but it is pulling all the records (as expected).

```
DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>("SELECT * FROM dbo.SomeDynamicView")
```

Problem is that `SqlQuery` returns [`DbRawSqlQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbrawsqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx) which is `IEnumerable`.

`dbo.SomeDynamicView` is a database view created at runtime.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic sql query"?

Comment: Dynamic SQL query.. SELECT * FROM SomeTable1 or SELECT * FROM SomeTable2.

Comment: You can very well get an IQueryable from ISQLQuery, but unfortunately only theoretically. You could create an enumerable from your SQLQuery object and a queryable from it. But the problem is that you can't create an enumerable from it, because it's just not supported. For this reason you can't create a queryable from the enumerable afterwards :-(

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, you can't get a `IQueryable` from `SqlQuery`<sup>*</sup>, this is because what `IQueryable` is doing is building a SQL string dynamically based on what select and where filters you put in. Because in `SqlQuery` you are providing the string Entity Framework can not generate that dynamic string.

Your options are either dynamically build the string your self to pass in to `SqlQuery` and use it as a `IEnumerable` instead of a `IQueryable` or use a `DbSet` in your `DbContext` and do the more "normal" way of letting entity framework build the query for you.

---

<sup>* You technically can by calling [AsQueryable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb353734(v=vs.100).aspx) on the result, but that is just a IEnumerable pretending to be a IQueryable, it does not give you any of the benefits of using a "Real" IQueryable like only retrieving the needed rows from the server.</sup>

Comment: "normal" way is only possible if I was doing simple stuff. Not everything in software development is straight forward. Anyways. Thanks for the answer at least now I know that I cant get IQueryable from a SQL query.

Comment: @1576573987 I think you are falling in to a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I suggest you ask a new question explaining why you think the "normal" way would not work and ask if there is something you are missing that would let it work.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I've tried the work around and it raises [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn313107) exception (when calling the `ToArrayAsync`), I return it as `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, which can be manipulated using the `System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable` exetension methods.

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is about EF6 but in case somebody else stumbles upon this question but interested in EFCore, this is actually possible there.

- [Source from Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)

**Most simple example:**

```
var user = new SqlParameter("user", "johndoe");

var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.GetMostPopularBlogsForUser @user", user)
    .ToList();
```

**Parameters:**

```
var user = new SqlParameter("user", "johndoe");

var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.GetMostPopularBlogs @filterByUser=@user", user)
    .ToList();
```

**More complex example (this is more specifically what this question is asking for):**

```
var searchTerm = ".NET";

var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchBlogs({searchTerm})")
    .Where(b => b.Rating > 3)
    .OrderByDescending(b => b.Rating)
    .ToList();
```

**Resulting query for more complex example:**

```
SELECT [b].[Id], [b].[Name], [b].[Rating]
        FROM (
            SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchBlogs(@p0)
        ) AS b
        WHERE b."Rating" > 3
        ORDER BY b."Rating" DESC
```

A few notes about this method:

- You effectively have to do a `SELECT *` to make sure all columns are returned from the table.
- Joins to pull back additional data don't work, but `Include` does in normal SQL queries (not necessarily stored proc/function calls).
- Often times your raw Sql will be put into a subquery. So make sure it's valid for such things (i.e. semicolons, order bys, hints, etc. can cause problems).