# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbSqlQuery’ to 'System.Linq.IQueryable’

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I created an Entity Framework API Controller and now I am trying to adjust my GetData() method from:

```
public IQueryable<VIPPreviewTimeSlots> GetData()
{
    return db.Data;
}
```

to

```
public IQueryable<VIPPreviewTimeSlots> GetData()
{
    return db.Data.SqlQuery("SELECT a,b,c FROM table INNER JOIN another table....");
}
```

but I get this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbSqlQuery’ to 'System.Linq.IQueryable’
```

How do I cast this to a IQueryable?

Comment: I would think by adding .AsQueryable() to the end of your return statement would work. However, according to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26143571/using-sqlquery-to-get-iqueryable) you cannot. You can change the function signature to return an IEnumerable

Comment: .AsQueryable() worked!

Comment: @PaulStoner That SO answer is about calling `.AsQueryable` on a `.SqlQuery`.  Changing the function signature to an IEnumerable will cause it to no longer be able to be lazily chainable.  Everything afterward will then be done client-side instead of server-side.  `.AsQueryable` is the correct answer here (and it actually would be the correct answer on your linked question as well, but it has possible performance implications on `.SqlQuery` where here it does not.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Thank you for that input. I, personally felt AsQueryable() would work as I have used it in similar cases, but not with EF. Always appreciate input,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using AsQuearable(). But as I noted in my comment, that can have repercussions.